# jquery append function with span tag

Tags: jquery, html, tags, append

```
ContactName = "ABC" 
phoneNumber = "123" 
phoneNumberType = "mobi"
```

I am trying as below:

```
tbody.append($('<tr>')
     .append($('<td>'+ contactName + '</br >' + 
         '<span id= phoneNumber onClick= reply_click(this.id)>phoneNumber</span>' + 
         phoneNumberType +'</td>')));
```

I am unable to get value 123 I am getting phonenumber as text.tried applying '' & "" to variable.

Comment: .append($('<td>'+ contactName + '</br >' + 
                        '<span id= phoneNumber onClick= reply_click(this.id)>phoneNumber</span>'
                        + phoneNumberType +'</td>')

Comment: To improve your question, use the "edit" link under the question. To put code in your question, the toolbar in the editor (in particular the `{}` button) and take the time to **read** the wide variety of help information available from the **[?]** button and the information displayed to the right of the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `phoneNumber` inside a string, so it won't be seen as an identifier, just as text.

Move it out of the string:

```
tbody.append($('<tr>')
  .append($('<td>'+ contactName + '</br >' + 
     '<span id= phoneNumber onClick= reply_click(this.id)>' + phoneNumber + '</span>' + 
     phoneNumberType +'</td>')));
```

Comment: OnClick i should get value of id that is 123 but i am getting phonenumber as text. please help me. :(

Comment: @user3771712: When the event happens `this` is the element, so you get the id of the element. If you have an id when you create the element, you would move that out of the string too: `... onClick= reply_click(' + this.id + ')> ...`

Answer (score 0):

tbody.append($('')
  .append($(''+ contactName + '' + 
     '' + phoneNumber + '' + 
     phoneNumberType +'')));